# После вывода функции из ооп она выдаёт unefinde

Tags: javascript, jquery, ооп

Всем привет, помогите реализовать функцию `checkError`. Функция постоянно выводит 1 и если вывести `console.log(validateFunc.inputLength())` выводит `undefined` а должно 1 или 2 в соответствие с  логическим выражением

```
$(function() {
  var elem1 = $('.length1');

  function Validate(elem1) {
    this.elem1 = elem1;
    var done1 = $('#1');
    elem1.on('input', this.inputLength = function() {
      if (isNaN(elem1.val()) || elem1.val() == '' || elem1.val() == ' ' || elem1.val() == 0) {
        elem1.attr('id', 'error');
        done1.addClass('hide');
        error = true;
      } else {
        elem1.attr('id', '');
        done1.removeClass('hide');
        var elem1Sum = parseInt(elem1.val())
        error = false
      }
      return console.log(error)
    })
  )

  function checkError() {
    var validateFunc = new Validate(elem1, elem2);
    if (validateFunc.inputLength() != false) {
      console.log(1)
    } else {
      console.log(2)
    }
  }
  checkError();
});
```

Comment: откуда был взят данный код?

Answer (score 0):

1. `Validate` принимает только один параметр `function Validate(elem1) {` однако в него пытаются передать два: `new Validate(elem1, elem2)`.
2. функция `inputLength` возвращает **результат выполнения** `console.log`, результат выполнения данной функции `undefined`. Так как больше ничего не возвращается, получается закономерный результат: `undefined` уже в вызывающем коде.

---

Для решения достаточно просто возвращать `error`.

Comment: Да пробовал писать return error но но он по прежнему возвращает undefind

Comment: @ВладимирБогданович, кто оно? Где пробовал писать? Как проверял? Ошибки я указал.